# RESTful API resource returns 404 when added @QueryParam

Tags: rest, jax-rs, http-status-code-404, restful-url, query-string

My resource worked fine till now. I added @QueryParam there. If I make request without writing query param to uri it works fine. After I write query param to the uri 404 code responses.

```
@GET
    @Path("{id}/appointments")
    @UnitOfWork
    @JsonView(Views.DoctorView.class)
    public List<?> getDoctorAppointments(@Auth LoggedUser loggedUser,
                                         @QueryParam("date") Date date,
                                         @QueryParam("timePeriod") TimePeriod timePeriod,
                                         @PathParam("id") int id
                                         ) {
        if(date != null && (timePeriod == null || timePeriod.equals(TimePeriod.TODAY))){
            return appointmentDAO.getDoctorsAppointmentsByDate(id, date);
        }
        if(date != null && timePeriod.equals(TimePeriod.WEEK)){
            return appointmentDAO.getDoctorsNumberOfAppointmentsForWeek(date, id);
        }
        return appointmentDAO.getAppointments(id, UserType.DOCTOR);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 404 I suspect you're not issuing the HTTP request correctly. My assumption for the query w/out a `date` or `timePeriod` param you'll be issuing

```
GET http://my-site/1/appointments
```

And if you try to pass a date and are getting a 404 you are issuing

```
GET http://my-site/1/appointments/date=2017-01-13
```

Or maybe this

```
GET http://my-site/1/appointments/2017-01-13
```

Which would result in a 404, whereas this should work fine and pass in the `date` query param

```
GET http://my-site/1/appointments?date=2017-01-13
```

I may be guessing wrong. Let me know what the URLs you're querying look like and we can troubleshoot more.

Comment: I already solved that. The problem was that date query param was util.Date in java. I changed it to String then cast it and it works now :)

Comment: That saved my day, what a weird behavior, to return a 404 instead of returning a reasonable error message... Thanks, @MartinPach for sharing

Answer (score 0):

The same question bothers me.

when the param is null,it will return 404.

http://127.0.0.1:8080/list?a=

```java
@QueryParam("a")
public Long a;
```

log:

```
023-02-13 18:20:49,547 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (executor-thread-0) [] Restarting handler chain for exception exception: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at com.mindflow.space.application.space.dto.SpaceUserRoleQuery.__quarkus_rest_inject(SpaceUserRoleQuery.java)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.parameters.InjectParamExtractor.extractParameter(InjectParamExtractor.java:26)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:45)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:142)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:564)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:721)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1163)
    at io.quarkus.generated.java.lang.Long$quarkusrestparamConverter$.convert(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```